# Need help to optimize the clickOutsideToClose of angular that is not working right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have a problem with a md-dialog in my project.

In all project dialogs, only one that has the functionality to close when clicked off, the rest is locked. I can do the lock by inserting the `clickOutsideToClose: false` directive in the code.

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'sascarReportAddonsModal',
    templateUrl: 'infra/template/sascar-report-addons/sascar-report-addons-modal.html',
    bindToController: true,
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    locals: {
        previousModal: vm.showSideDialog,
        selectedIndex: selectedIndex
    },
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    fullscreen: false
});
```

But in the dialog that the directive is `clickOutsideToClose: true` it does not work. I was able to work around this problem by adding in the dialog controller this code:

```
$timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);
function callAtTimeout() {
    angular.element(document).find("md-backdrop").on('click', function() {
        closeDialog();
    });
}
```

My question is, how can I make this code better without using the timeout. Make `angular.element(document).find("md-backdrop").on('click', function() { closeDialog();});` only load when the dialog completes loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying the dialogue to the code below and see if this helps:

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'sascarReportAddonsModal',
    templateUrl: 'infra/template/sascar-report-addons/sascar-report-addons-  
    modal.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
})
```

EDIT:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    angular.element(document).find("md-backdrop").on('click', function() {  
    closeDialog();});
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass all the other information, and the timeout is working.

I'd just like to give it an optimized one so it does not get too bad in code

Comment: I've added a slightly shorter method you can use implementing $apply rather than $timeout, which should do the trick.

Comment: That's great news - please accept the answer submitted. Glad to help!